# XSLT replace element with it's parent's name

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm an XSLT developer trying to do the following transformation:

SOURCE:

```
...
<student>
    <item>
        <contact>
            <item>
                <phone>000000001</phone>
            </item>
            <item>
                <phone>000000002</phone>
            </item>
        </contact>
        <name>John</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Francis</name>
    </item>
</student>

...
```

RESULT:

```
...
    <student>
        <contact>
            <phone></phone>
        </contact>
        <contact>
            <phone></phone>
        </contact>
        <name>John</name>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Francis</name>
    </student>

...
```

I want to replace each element "item" with it's parent's name, and then delete their own parent.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:element name="{parent::*/name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: The question needs more information. How about the root node? Would you like to do the same with the root node also? If you do so, you will end up producing invalid XML..

Comment: I updated the original post. There will never be an "item" element next to the root element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction was right, retrieving the element name from the parent is a good idea, but then

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".."/>
```

Would next process the nodes of the parent element. But instead, you should then proceed and process the content of the `item` element.

If you delete the `parent` element, then obviously the result would be malformed XML. So I assume the following XML input (with a `root` element around everything):

**XML Input**

```
<root>
<parent>
    <item>
        <val1>...</val1>
        <val2>...</val2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <val2>...</val2>
    </item>
</parent>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parent">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:element name="{parent::*/name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <parent>
      <val1>...</val1>
      <val2>...</val2>
   </parent>
   <parent>
      <val2>...</val2>
   </parent>
</root>
```

---

If the rules depend solely on the *hierarchy* of elements, try the following stylesheet. It does not mention any concrete element name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:element name="{parent::*/name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <parent>
      <val1>...</val1>
      <val2>...</val2>
   </parent>
   <parent>
      <val2>...</val2>
   </parent>
</root>
```

---

**EDIT**

Using @Ian's suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*][not(*[not(self::item)])]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:element name="{parent::*/name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<student>
   <contact>
      <phone>000000001</phone>
   </contact>
   <contact>
      <phone>000000002</phone>
   </contact>
   <name>John</name>
</student>
<student>
   <name>Francis</name>
</student>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that I don't know the item's parent name, which means I can't do a match of it.

Comment: @sovesky Then please look at the second stylesheet - I have edited my answer already.

Comment: thank you. I'm almost there. I updated the original post. The code works, but not for nested item structures.

Comment: @sovesky Edited my answer again, incorporating the template suggested by Ian.

Comment: @sovesky And if it turns out you do need XSLT 1.0 rather than 2.0 after all then the only thing you need to change in this stylesheet is to replace `parent::*/name()` with `name(..)`

Answer (score 2):

*This is an extension of the excellent answer from Matthias*

From your comments on the other answer it looks like:

- this parent/item structure could be anywhere in a larger document
- the "item" elements are always called `item` but the "parent" element could be called anything

The other answer gives the basic logic you need - an identity template taking care of most things, a template matching the parent that just does `apply-templates` and a template matching the `item` that takes the element name from the parent - but how do we match the parent if we don't know its name?  Well, how about this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*][not(*[not(self::item)])]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

This would match any element whose children are *all* named `item` (the double-negative says "there is no child element whose name is not item", but this would include the case of an element with no children at all so the initial `[*]` is necessary to ensure there is *at least one* child element).

Comment: I still think that's a big omission in xpath, where there's no way to specify a element where ALL children match a pattern, rather than any. The double negative is unfortunately necessary, and usually hard to debug if you get brackets wrong.

Comment: @Flynn1179 given the question is XSLT 2.0 (not explicitly mentioned but you can tell from the `../name()`) you could write it as `[every $n in * satisfies $n/name() eq 'item']`

Comment: Ah.. I'm too used to XSLT 1 unfortunately. Pretty much stuck with working with MSXSL or browsers doing transforms where I am. That's not necessarily the case though- it's possible the OP didn't realise that that didn't work in XSLT 1, after all that wasn't working.

Comment: @Flynn1179 indeed.  The double negative idiom looks a bit odd when you first see it but it is just that - an idiom - and once you get used to it you recognise the meaning without having to decode it every time.

Comment: +1 That's a useful extension to apply the logic anywhere in the hierarchy.

Comment: Just a thought, but `[count(*) = count(item)]` would also work, but I'm not sure if it's 'better'. Might be in some cases, depends on the context I suppose.